# How to stop zsh continuing bg job

Tags: process, zsh

Observe the following behaviour (which I want to stop happening):

```
> cat /dev/zero
[1]  + 36461 suspended  cat /dev/zero
> bg                                                                                                          
[1]  + 36461 continued  cat /dev/zero
> cat
[1]  + 36461 running    cat /dev/zero
```

I'm not sure why typing `cat` starts the old `cat` again, I want it to just start a new process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the zsh option `AUTO_RESUME` is on.

> AUTO_RESUME (-W)
>
> Treat single word simple commands without redirection as candidates for resumption of an existing job.
>
> -- [`ZSHOPTIONS(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTORESUME)

You could avoid this behavior globally with `setopt no_autoresume`.

Or just for *this command*, we could make it to not be a "single word" command. In this case, you could do it by prefixing some [precommand modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-precommand-modifiers) for example `command` and `-` like this:

```
> cat /dev/zero
[1]  + 6241 suspended  cat /dev/zero
> bg
[1]  + 6241 continued  cat /dev/zero
> cat
[1]  + 6241 running    cat /dev/zero

[1]  + 6241 suspended  cat /dev/zero
> - cat
```